# Date formation from variables

Tags: shell-script

I have 2 variables as below and need to change to whole date, could you please help me on this?
Thanks in advance.!!!

```
end=2020-03(yyyy-mm)
win=28
```

need this to be formated as below variables

```
start_timestamp = less 1 month from end + 1 day from win
end_timestamp= start_timestamp + 1 month – 1 days
```

Result:

```
start_timestamp = 2020-02-29
end_timestamp = 2020-03-28
```

Note: I'm using ksh

Comment: What did you already try? could you please clarify the formulas of the start and end timestamps?

Comment: could you please clarify which shell exactly you are using and which version of date?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get relative times from the `date` command you need the `--date` flag (please refer to the documentation for more details (e.g. `man date` and `info date`))
So in your case it would look like this:

```
end=2020-03
win=28

start_timestamp=$(date --date="${end}-${win} last month next day" +%Y-%m-%d)
end_timestamp=$(date --date="${start_timestamp} next month last day" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Comment: `--date` is only recognised by the GNU, busybox and ast-open implementations of `date`. With that `${end}-${win} last month next day` value however, it will only work with GNU `date`. If the OP's ksh is ksh93, note that ksh93 has builtin date manipulation features (with its `printf` builtin, some deployments also have ast-open `date` builtin).

Comment: Thanks much for your reply.!!! 

I tried with your code, but got below error

date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]